# Access bluemix object storage from local spark

Tags: apache-spark, ibm-cloud, jupyter-notebook, object-storage

I can't access files on object storage from my local standalone spark cluster. This is the code -

```
sqlCxt = SQLContext(sc)
prefix = "fs.swift.service." + creds['name']
hconf = sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration()
hconf.set(prefix + ".auth.url", creds['auth_url'] + '/v2.0/tokens')
hconf.set(prefix + ".auth.endpoint.prefix", "endpoints")
hconf.set(prefix + ".tenant", creds['project_id'])
hconf.set(prefix + ".username", creds['user_id'])
hconf.set(prefix + ".password", creds['password'])
hconf.setInt(prefix + ".http.port", 8080)
hconf.set(prefix + ".region", creds['region'])
hconf.setBoolean(prefix + ".public", True)

weather = sqlCxt.read.json("swift://notebooks." + creds['name'] + "/repo_local.json")
weather.show()
```

This is the exception I am getting

```
16/04/21 17:31:11 INFO JSONRelation: Listing swift://notebooks.pac/repo_local.json on driver
16/04/21 17:31:11 WARN HttpMethodDirector: Unable to respond to any of these challenges: {keystone=Keystone uri="https://identity.open.softlayer.com"}
16/04/21 17:31:33 INFO SparkContext: Created broadcast 0 from json at NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:-2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\MY_PC\Desktop\PAC\src\unittest\python\PAC\ObjectStorage_tests.py", line 18, in <module>
    weather = sqlCxt.read.json("swift://notebooks.pac/config-repo_local.json")
  File "C:\Python27\lib\pyspark\sql\readwriter.py", line 176, in json
    return self._df(self._jreader.json(path))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\py4j\java_gateway.py", line 813, in __call__
    answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\pyspark\sql\utils.py", line 45, in deco
    return f(*a, **kw)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\py4j\protocol.py", line 308, in get_return_value
    format(target_id, ".", name), value)
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o22.json.
: java.io.IOException: No input paths specified in job
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.listStatus(FileInputFormat.java:201)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.getSplits(FileInputFormat.java:313)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD.getPartitions(HadoopRDD.scala:199)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:239)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:237)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:237)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.getPartitions(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:35)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:239)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:237)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:237)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.getPartitions(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:35)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:239)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:237)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:237)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$treeAggregate$1.apply(RDD.scala:1115)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:150)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:111)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:316)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.treeAggregate(RDD.scala:1113)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.json.InferSchema$.infer(InferSchema.scala:65)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.json.JSONRelation$$anonfun$4.apply(JSONRelation.scala:114)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.json.JSONRelation$$anonfun$4.apply(JSONRelation.scala:109)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.json.JSONRelation.dataSchema$lzycompute(JSONRelation.scala:109)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.json.JSONRelation.dataSchema(JSONRelation.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.sources.HadoopFsRelation.schema$lzycompute(interfaces.scala:636)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.sources.HadoopFsRelation.schema(interfaces.scala:635)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.LogicalRelation.<init>(LogicalRelation.scala:37)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:125)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:109)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.json(DataFrameReader.scala:244)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:95)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:56)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:620)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:231)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:381)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:259)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:133)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:209)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:801)
```

Please note - I am able to access the file when I am running through notebook or spark-submit within bluemix.

Also I was able to access file through swift CLI.

Answer (score 1):

The swift would need authentication token to connect to object storage from your local environment via keystone authentication.

I would suggest trying out Stocator connector to access bluemix object storage , it worked out for me pretty consistently.

https://github.com/SparkTC/stocator

Thanks,
Charles.